# Bootstrap - constructing a fluid grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a number of items that I want to display 4 across on a large screen, 3 across on a smaller screen, two across on smaller and so on.

I have each group of 4 elements in a row with each having the classes: `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3`.

The problem is when the screen is shrank to the point where the elements are displaying three in a row, it's displaying three and then one, like this:

1 1 1

1

1 1 1

1

1 1 1

1

How can I get it so that the next row starts on the same line as the previous when displaying in threes ?

Comment: Do your columns have content that makes them different heights?

Answer (score 0):

Boostrap uses percents to dislpay colums, so if needed nice grid i always do like that:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
  ...
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was doing originally but the problem is, I want a 'click to reveal' div to appear at the bottom of the corresponding row when an item is clicked on. This will not work if all of the items are in the same row

Answer (score 0):

change `col-md-4` to `col-md-3`. because a full grid width is 12. and if you want to display 4 divs side by side you need to change it to `col-*-3` (12/4 = 3).

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the website referenced below, I'm sure it will help you with this greatly. It's a graphical bootstrap grid 'designer'.

http://shoelace.io/